# Is it possible to change the value of a callBackElement from within a handler function?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a handler function that is updating a quite large UI with values from a spreadsheet. The rowindex of the sheet comes from a callbackElement as `e.parameter.hidden` (hidden is the widget that holds the value) and that I increment/decrement in the function.

I have another handler function that searches the spreadsheet for a string value and returns a rowindex that I assign to this same hidden widget.

If I trigger the 'search' handler *first* and *then* the 'display' handler, I have my UI updated with the 'found' data, which is nice but needs two separate clicks on two distinct buttons.

**Now my question :** how could I include in the 'search handler function' a call to the 'display handler' and pass all e.parameters **BUT** modify the value of the `e.parameter.hidden` only ?

I know `e` is an object with a lot of keys and values but I don't know how to manipulate just one value in there...

The code of the search handler is very short and goes like this :

```
function findname(e){ // this function is called by a handler triggered by a keypress on  a textBox
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var hiddenD = app.getElementById('hiddenD');
  var str = e.parameter.find ; // find is the textBox's name
  var found = point(str);// point() is a function that returns the rowindex of the found value
  hiddenD.setValue(found);// hiddenD is the hidden widget that I want to 'manipulate'
  nextitem(e);// nextitem is the function that updates the UI and that is normally called by a handler on another button
return app
}
```

*Well I hope this question is clear enough (this wasn't easy to explain), if not please ask ;-)*

Comment: Hi Serge,

Do you mean: Updating a widget value on the go?

https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/apps-script/lABoP-cJcGQ/discussion

This solution works, I have used it several times.


I assume you don't mean

    e.parameter.hidden = "new value";
    doDisplay(e);

Comment: Thanks Eddy, the widget updates its 'shown value' (talking about a hidden widget it's kind of funny ;-) on the next 'return' when I use Waqar's solution... thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e is just a json data which you can manipulate by its key.

Code skeleton is like

```
searchHandlerFunction(e){
//Your all other sttements
//Assign the new value to hidden parameter
e.parameter.hidden = <your new value>;
DisplayFunction(e);
}
```

Comment: May be, you will have to pass the app instance too

Comment: Hmmm... as simple as that !? I should be ashamed not knowing that  ;-)  thanks a lot, works nicely .

Comment: @Serge insas: There is nothing to be ashamed of. We just learn from each other. I am always inspired with your dedication to the forum.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably the 'nicest comment of the day', they should create a badge for that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply store the rowIndex as a CacheService property ? I'm using this with a lot of success in lieu of hidden fields and hidden text boxes.

You can call them from anywhere and modify them anywhere.

Comment: You have a point here, this would be a good solution but I just like to be able to actually 'see' values while developing the script and so I replace this hidden widget by a textBox during this development and change it to hidden when everything works... maybe not the smartest idea but I like it and since the logger is not available in handler functions it proved to be a great help for me ;-).  Anyway, thanks for the suggestion !